# How to address a matched selector in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I imagine this is simple and some sort of a scoping problem- yet I am stuck. In the code below, I'd like to see an alert with either "foo!" or "bar!' when I mouse over the div's.  Instead I see empty content.  How do I address the current element that matched the selector from the spot where I have the alert()? TIA.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test Case</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" />

    <!-- Tooltip classes -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/tip-yellow/tip-yellow.css" type="text/css" />

    <!-- jQuery and the Poshy Tip plugin files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/jquery.poshytip.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        $(function(){
            $("span[name='entity']").poshytip({
                className: 'tip-yellow',
                content: function(updateCallback) {
                            var title = $(this).attr('title');
                            alert(title);
                            updateCallback(title);
                          },
                showTimeout: 1,
                alignTo: 'target',
                alignX: 'center',
                offsetY: 5,
                allowTipHover: true
            });
        });
        //              
        //]]>
    </script>   
</head>

<body>
    <p><span name="entity" title="foo!">Hover for a tooltip 1</span></p>
    <p><span name="entity" title="bar!">Hover for a tooltip 2</span></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selection using `$(this).attr('title')` is correct. However, since poshytip uses the title attribute internally, it appears to be modifying the title attribute temporarily. You can see this behavior by setting a breakpoint there: `$(this)` references the span, but the title is blank.

When you select the span outside of the content callback, the title is there -- for example, from a debugger using `$("span").attr("title")`

Since poshytip's purpose is to give you enhanced tooltips, this is probably expected. In fact, if you remove your content function entirely, you will see that the correct title / tooltip pops up:

```
    $(function(){
        $("span[name='entity']").poshytip({
            className: 'tip-yellow',
            showTimeout: 1,
            alignTo: 'target',
            alignX: 'center',
            offsetY: 5,
            allowTipHover: true
        });
    });
```

Specifying the content method is useful for calculating the title (e.g. if you wanted to return some other value, from content, the tooltip would display it).

Also, the updateCallback is mainly used to update the tooltip asynchronously:
http://vadikom.com/demos/poshytip/#async-content

Comment: Great- thank you, it did not occur to me that poshytip might be manipulating the title attribute.  This is a simplified test case, in fact in my real implementation the poshytip content will come from an asynchronous HTTP call.  The value of the title attrib was going to be a GUID that gets passed as a GET param.  Instead, it appears I should use the name or id attrib instead since those are not disturbed by poshytip.

Answer (score 1):

Tooltip plugins typically remove the title value so browser default display won't also show them. In the case of this plugin it stores the original within data of the element itself. A quick look through the plugin source code shows it being stored as `title.poshytip` using jQuery `data()` method

TRY

```
alert( $(this).data('title.poshytip' ))
```

Answer (score 0):

I do believe you are missing the simplicity of poshytip. When you say alert, do you mean a literal javascript alert, or a poshytip message. Because if you want a poshytip message, all you have to do is add the appropriate class, i.e. `.tip-darkgray`, and then call the `.poshytip' method on it, which should implement all of the handlers for you.

example:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("span[name='poshy']").poshytip();
  });
</script>

<span name="poshy" title="So Poshy"></span>
```

Also, don't forget to wrap all of your jQuery in DOM Ready.